# Does SciPy.sparse.linalg.svds give matrix rank?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have a largish sparse binary-valued rectangular matrix, **M**, where *n* > *m*. My understanding of matrix rank suggests the largest possible rank is *m*, and my understanding of SVD suggests the rank of a matrix can be found by identifying the number of non-zero singular values.

I'm attempting to use SciPy.sparse.linalg.svds to determine the rank of **M**. First problem is that I cannot compute *m* singular values since *k* can only go up to *p* = *m* - 1. So I thought I'd be clever and compute *p* highest values, the *p* lowest values, combine them, run `set` to find the unique values, and end up with a list of at most *m* values. This didn't work out according to plan.

Here's a MWE:

```
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg
import numpy
import itertools  

m = 6
n = 10

test = scipy.sparse.rand(m, n, density=0.25, format='lil', dtype=None, random_state=None)

for i, j in itertools.product(list(range(m)), list(range(n))):
     test[i, j] = 1 if test[i, j] > 0 else 0

U1, S1, VT1 = scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(test, k = min(test.shape) - 1, ncv = None, tol = 1e-5, which = 'LM', v0 = None, maxiter = None, 
                                    return_singular_vectors = True)

U2, S2, VT2 = scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(test, k = min(test.shape) - 1, ncv = None, tol = 1e-5, which = 'SM', v0 = None, maxiter = None, 
                                    return_singular_vectors = True)

S = list(set(numpy.concatenate((S1, S2), axis = 0)))

len(S)
```

Here's a sample output:

```
10
```

with `S` being

```
[0.5303120147925737,
 1.0725314055439354,
 2.7940865631779643,
 1.5060744813473148,
 1.8412737686034186,
 0.3208993522030293,
 0.5303120147925728,
 1.072531405543936,
 1.5060744813473153,
 1.841273768603419]
```

How can a *m* X *n* matrix with *m* < *n* have a rank of *n*? Are my assumptions above incorrect, or am I misapplying the function? My real **M** is sparse, binary-valued, and roughly 300 X 500.

Thanks for looking!

---

With help from @tch I've come up with the following hack. To check for rank = *m*, I only need check the smallest value, and append it to the *m* - 1 values obtained from the svds highest values function. It turns out svds doesn't report 0s when thresholded, so the lowest values function will return nan for rank < *m*. Here's the revised code:

```
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg
import numpy
import itertools

m = 6
n = 10

test = scipy.sparse.rand(m, n, density=0.25, format='lil', dtype=None, random_state=None)

test = test > 0
test = test.astype('d')

U1, S1, VT1 = scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(test, k = min(test.shape) - 1, ncv = None, tol = 1e-5, which = 'LM', v0 = None, maxiter = None, 
                                    return_singular_vectors = True)

U2, S2, VT2 = scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(test, k = 1, ncv = None, tol = 1e-5, which = 'SM', v0 = None, maxiter = None, 
                                    return_singular_vectors = True)

S = list(set(numpy.concatenate((S1, S2), axis = 0)))

print(sum(x > 1e-10 for x in S))
S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do would work in exact arithmetic (assuming the matrix has no repeat singular values). However, due to numerical rounding errors, it won't work in practice.

To see this try

```
C = np.random.randn(10,3)
u,s,vt = np.linalg.svd(C@C.T)
```

Note that `C@C.T` is a 10x10 matrix with rank 3. However, you will see that none of the singular values are exactly zero (however 7 are close to 0).

When finding the rank of a matrix numerically, thresholding is often used to determine what it means for a singular value to be `0`. For instance, everything below `1e-10` may be set to zero.

If the matrix has exact rank `k`, hopefully you will see `k` singular values away from `0`, and then `min(m,n)-k` singular values very close to zero. However, depending on the matrix, there may not even be a well defined "drop".

So for your example, you could try removing elements which are within some threshold of one another. However this of course could run into issues if the matrix has repeat singular values.

You could just run the smallest singular values and see how many give you near zero. Presumably the matrix is at least rank ` so the first singular value will be nonzero.

As a note about finding where `test[i,j] > 0`, you can just to `test>0` and it will give a boolean array with `True` in the nonzero entries and `False` elsewhere. You can also set the `dtype` of the random matrix to `bool` and it will be `True` whenever the random number is nonzero.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'd set my threshold (*tol* option) to 1e-5 in hopes of avoiding machine errors. I ran your code, thanks for that, and you have values close to zero that would fall under a threshold, but all values in my S aren't even close to zero! And thanks also for the shortcut on the binary conversions. I'll use that.

Comment: The example was meant to illustrate that nothing is exact, so if you want to use a `set` to eliminate repeat elements, you also have to threshold those comparisons. However, you still run the risk of removing repeat singular values.

Comment: Yes, I could run set with a threshold! Looking at my S, there are many values that are very close together. Thanks!

Comment: I just edited my post, but you really only need to find the lowest singular values and count how many are zero. I think it is probably best to avoid set because otherwise you could delete repeat singular values.

Comment: Will do . . . wouldn't want to delete repeats.

Comment: BTW, any reason why I can't actually seek *m* singular values in the svds function? That would eliminate the hacking.

Comment: My lowest singular value from svds for my real **M** is 0.11895323. I have no zeros.